# Java data structure to hold a set of items, String & date that can be iterated through

Tags: java, data-structures, hashset

I am currently storing strings in a HashSet but I would like to pair each string with a date object. The date will be used as a decay timer (set a date for the string so after that day has passed it can be removed). When the program starts up I want to iterate through the list and check the dates of all the strings, removing those that have expired.

Is there a 2-tuple data structure that will allow me to iterate through the list and has a contains method?

Also, if I was too switch to a list data structure rather than a set, how much does iterating the data structure affect the performance, in comparison to HashSet which has a `.contains(string)` method when trying to find out if the string exists? The check needs to be relatively quick, preferably under a second.

Comment: Soounds like you want a  `Map` instead of a `Set`.

Comment: Appart from a map, you could write your own class which has a string and a date field, then override the equals method such that it appropriately compares the string and dates with an object of the same type. That way the .contains method of collection types like ArrayList<> wont have any issue comparing your types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a

```
Map<String,Date> stringDateMap = new HashMap<String,Date>();
```

Instead of a set, as a set doesn't do any mapping.

You can put more data in by doing so:

```
stringDateMap.put("Key1", new Date());
```

You can remove that same data by doing so:

```
stringDateMap.remove("Key1");
```

Check out the other functionality here
[Hash Map Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this :

```
        Map<Date,List<String>> map = new HashMap<Date,List<String>>();
```

For iterating over all the elements from the map :

```
for (Date date : map.keySet()) {
        // Check with current date and remove from map if date has expired
        }
```

I will suggest you to use List, instead of Set as it will always make a function call to check if element is already present in the Set or not. Hence, if you are not bothered about duplicates then go for List.

Comment: user wants to Check String for Date not Date for String.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Tuple in java, but you can very easily create one urself.

```
public class StringDatePair {

    private final String str;
    private final Date date;

    public StringDatePair(String str, Date date) {
        this.str = str;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public getString() {
        return str;
    }
    public getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

If you want to make this tuple sortable when in a list you can implement `Comparable` and compare by date.

Sets are faster than lists when checking contains, and the difference gets bigger as the contents of the set/list gets bigger. But there have to be a really big amount of content to have a running time > 1sec for checking if a item exists in a list.

Also if you end up using a list which have sorted the items by date, you can iterate the list from the start and when you find the first item with an unexpired date you can throw away all earlier items.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a generic `Pair` class to be extremely useful:

```
public class Pair<T, R> {

    T first;
    R second;

    public Pair(T first, R second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public T getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public R getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Pair pair = (Pair) o;

        if (first != null ? !first.equals(pair.first) : pair.first != null) return false;
        if (second != null ? !second.equals(pair.second) : pair.second != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = first != null ? first.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (second != null ? second.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```